# C# End Task not End Process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Another question here.
 I Just want to know if it is possible to End Task those Application using C#.

Like: there are 4 Notepad application opened. i just want to close the 2nd Notepad Application. but when i tried to use process.Kill, all 4 Notepad are being closed. is there any way to close only the specified Noteped?

Here is my sample Code:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
{
    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, 31) == "NotepadName.txt")
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are looping through all the processes and killing all the one that have NotepadName.text... Change your algorithm to kill the second one, and leave the loop when it is done

Comment: maybe all of your notepad applications has the same title ? It's always a good approach to kill a process by its ID if it is possible

Comment: It just continually amazes me how many C# programmers there are out there trying to automate Notepad. Just drop an edit control on your form. Boom, you have instant control over your *own* Notepad.

Comment: _i just want to close the 2nd Notepad Application_ - how do you define "2nd"?

Comment: i got 4 Notepad App. namely(in exact order): NotepadName1.txt, NotepadName.txt, NotepadName3.txt and NotepadName4.txt..... Normally, the first notepad(NotepadName1.txt) will be ignored. the 2nd one will be the process that should only be closed. The problem is that all 4 notepad app. are being closed when i call p.Kill();.  Thanks btw!..^_^

Answer (score 3):

You need to use process start time to find second run Notepad.

```
Process[] processes = (from prc in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
                       orderby prc.StartTime
                       select prc).ToArray();

if (processes.Count() > 1)
    processes[1].Kill();
```

Comment: One cannot rely on PIDs distribution mechanism. Basically, the only thing you should know about PID is that it doesn't change over time and is unique at any given point of time.

Comment: I do not mean to rely on particular process IDs but on the sequence they create. I have rephrased my answer.

Comment: If you are not using the PID to identify the process you want to kill you shouldn't really be doing it, because you could kill other processes in an unintended way.  Why do you need to close the 2nd notepad and not as in you example the other 4?

Comment: That is true, process IDs can be reused but this will work most of the time. I do not know if there is any other, better mechanism.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm saying about. There is no any contractual obligations for PIDs to be issued in the same order as the processes are created. The only things you should know about PID is that it is a number; that at any given time there is only one active process with any given pid; and that for any given process, its PID doesn't change over time. You can think of PID as of random unique number issued on the process start.

Answer (score 0):

You iterating across all processes in the `foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))` loop and killing any process with a title that begins `"NotepadName.txt"`.

If you want to kill only the second instance you'll have to modify the logic in the loop to be more selective.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
{
    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, 31) == "NotepadName.txt")
        {
            i++;
            if(i == 2){
                p.Kill();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to kill only the second instance, one should define what do they mean by "second" or what order do they use to number the processes. Your code is basically kills _some_ notepad process (if there is more than one notepad process). Not _second_, but _some_.

Comment: I am aware of the shortcomings of this code. This is an amendment to the OP's original code. The OP simply states "i just want to close the 2nd Notepad Application." and doesn't specify `what do they mean by "second"`. If you have more information please post an answer.

Comment: I already asked the OP what do they mean by "second", but I'm sure they didn't mean "some". And your code may confuse people, because in attempt to kill _some_ process it does some things with `i` which is unneeded at all, as if choosing the value at a specific index in Process.GetProcesses made sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mean you only want to close the notepad process that is viewing the NotepadName.txt file. You are probably trying to deny access to the file (or close whoever is accessing it for whatever reason). Therefore I am ignoring "2nd" part.

I ran your code and tested it, and was able to close only the notepad process that was accessing the file I targeted.

However what I noticed is that your comparison is definitely not correct.

```
//not all processes have a string of 31 characters 
//so sometimes it will trigger an exception
if (p.MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, 31) == "NotepadName.txt") 
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
```

For your purpose, replace with

```
if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("NotepadName.txt"))
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
```

From the tests I ran, this should work.

Comment: My fault. it should only be:
if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToString == "")
{
p.Kill(); 
} //Thanks btw.

Comment: if you got it working remember to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of messing up with PIDs, so i have to write a cleaner answer to the question everybody are answering to (although that might not be an original question).

So, in order to kill the second (**in the order of process start time**) process fullfilling the conditions in your example, you should write

```
var processToKill = (from p in Process.GetProcesses(".") where p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0 and p.MainWindowTitle.Substring(0, 31) == "NotepadName.txt" order by p.StartTime).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
if(processToKill != null)
{
    processToKill.Kill();
}
```